# Enviar archivo de una api a otra en laravel 7

Tags: laravel, guzzle

Quiero enviar un archivo de una api a otra de forma LAN, es decir que trabajo con 2 computadoras una que funciona como servidor y otra cliente.

Al enviar un archivo desde el pc-cliente se ejecuta esta función, donde se guarda el archivo dentro de mi proyecto y se guarda la dirección del archivo en mi BD:

Despues realizo una peticion ala otra pc-servidor, donde le envio el mismo archivo.

```
public function guardar_archivo(Request $request){
        if($request->hasFile('file')){
            $extension = $request->file('file')->extension();
            if($extension == 'pdf'){
                $path =Storage::disk('public')->putFile('archivos',$request->file); //Aqui guardo el archivo y retorna la direccion donde se guardo
                $nuevoArchivo = new Archivo();
                $nuevoArchivo->name = $request->name;
                $nuevoArchivo->file = $path;
                $nuevoArchivo->save();
                 //Aqui mando el archivo a la otra pc (pc-servidor)
                $response = Http::asMultipart()->post('http://192.168.2.10:8000/api/archivo/enviar', [
                    'name'=>$request->name,
                    'file'=> $request->file
                    ]);
                return $response->json();
                }
        }
```

y esta es la funcion se ejecuta en la pc-servidor donde pc-cliente le envio el archivo

```
public function guardar(Request $request){
        if($request->hasFile('file')){
                $path = Storage::disk('public')->putFile('archivo',$request->file); //Aqui guardo el archivo y retorna la direccion donde se guardo

                $nuevoArchivo = new Documento();
                $nuevoArchivo->name = $request->name;
                $nuevoArchivo->file = $path;
                $nuevoArchivo->save();

                return Storage::download($path); //aqui retorno el archivo y se muestra
        }
    }
```

al enviar el archivo a la pc-servidor pretendo hacer lo mismo que en la pc-cliente, guardar el archivo en mi proyecto laravel y guardar la dirección del archivo en una BD.

Su poniendo que se guardo el archivo exitosamente en la pc-servidor mandado por el pc-cliente, la respuesta de pc-servidor será el archivo que se mando. Es decir pc-cliente guarda el archivo y después lo envía a pc-servidor mientras que pc-cliente espera la respuesta de pc-servidor mientras pc-servidor guarda el archivo y después le envía la respuesta a pc-cliente que seria el archivo que pando pc-cliente.

El problema es que al momento de enviar el archivo a la pc-servidor este archivo no llega es decir que no lo guarda.

Mi pregunta es como puedo guardar el archivo enviado de pc-cliente en mi pc-servidor y despues retornar el archivo.

Nota:
creo que tengo una avance, al enviar el archivo lo recibo pero como un archivo temporal

Gracias!!

Comment: Tienes ambos proyectos funcionando? Imagino que debes tener uno en un puerto y el otro en otro.

Comment: Asi es, cada computadora tiene una IP asignada y están en Lan. Otra cosa, encontré la librería guzzle pero no se como implementarlo.